# Как сделать пересекающиеся оси на d3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Добрый день! Создаю стандартные оси OX, OY. Все замечательно, но нулевая точка обозначается по каждой из осей, причем текст пересекается самой осью. Есть ли хорошие способы либо в принципе убрать одну из засечек, либо передвинуть текст? (использую 4-ую версию библиотеки)
[Изменения в 4-ой версии](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md)

[Документация](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki)

```js
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-2, 2])
  .range([-200, 200]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-2, 2])
  .range([200, -200]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(xScale)
  .ticks(8);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .ticks(8);

d3.select("svg").append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 250 + "," + 250 + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

d3.select("svg").append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 250 + "," + 250 + ")")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="500" height="500">
     </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел такое решение. Добавляем метод tickFormat для осей. И далее в функции, если значение равно нулю, меняем на null. Остальные без изменений. При этом нули исчезают. В принцип можно пойти дальше и как-то нарисовать ноль рядом с пересечением, но меня и так устраивает уже.

```js
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-2, 2])
  .range([-200, 200]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-2, 2])
  .range([200, -200]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(xScale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    if (d == 0) {
      return null
    } else {
      return d
    }
  });

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    if (d == 0) {
      return null
    } else {
      return d
    }
  });

d3.select("svg").append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 250 + "," + 250 + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

d3.select("svg").append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 250 + "," + 250 + ")")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <svg width="500" height="500">
     </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Что-то в сниппете надо поправить. Кроме ошибки **"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined"** ничего не вижу Или у меня одного только так? Плюс за работу (+), я так понял, что у вас на домашнем ПК всё в порядке.

Comment: Не понял, где не работает? При нажатии на "Выполнить код"?

Comment: да, При нажатии на "Выполнить код"

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbiiA.png

Comment: эээ.. я, если честно, не знаю как поправить. У меня и домашнем и на рабочем ПК все нормально.

Comment: У меня, тоже вчера были такие же проблемы со сниппетом -- http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/649206/28748 решил заменой на подходящую  версию библиотеки Можно попробовать ещё, прямо в сниппете, есть пункт меню -- добавить внешнюю библиотеку

Comment: Вставил через "добавить внешнюю библиотеку". Скрипт вставился в первую строчку html. Ну пусть так. Из head удалил. Вроде работает. Попробуйте запустить.

Comment: ещё немного уточнений (вы не возражаете?)<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> в сниппете не надо писать - они лишние для него

Comment: убрал эти теги. Видимо это где то написано? я не видел просто.

Comment: может и написано где, не могу указать конкретное место на нашем сайте:-) Но это обычная практика - на других ресурсах при добавлении в сниппет тегов заголовков они подсвечиваются красным цветом, либо выводится поясняющая надпись, что они лишние.

Answer (score 2):

**Может SVG попробовать?**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
       width="420px" height="420px" viewbox="0 0 420 420" >
  
    <defs>
       <pattern id="pattern1"
           x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20"
           patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
     
          <g fill="none" stroke-width="1px" stroke="#CCCCCC">
           <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" />
           <rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" />
          </g> 
      </pattern> 
   
     <marker id="MarkerArrow"    refX="0" refY="2"
             markerUnits="strokeWidth" orient="auto"
        markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" >
        <polyline id="markerPoly1" points="0,0 10,2 0,4 2,2 0,0"
         fill-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" fill="none"  />
    </marker>
  </defs>
    
       <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />     
  
   <g style="stroke-width:1px; stroke:black; marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);">    
    <!--  axis X  -->
 <line x1="20" y1="200" x2="400" y2="200"  /> 
    
 <!-- axis Y  -->
 <line x1="210" y1="400" x2="210" y2="20"  />   
  </g> 
  
  <text x="222" y="195"  style=" font-size: 14px; text-anchor: middle">0,0</text>    
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @andrey.ilinskiy вам именно такую надо было систему координат? Если другую, например - начало координат в левом верхнем углу, как у SVG или как-то другой вариант, не стесняйтесь:- напишите, добавлю вариант.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но хочется использовать возможности именно d3.js. Библиотека мощная и должно же что-то быть. Она тоже создает оси используя SVG, но в дополнение мы имеем и возможность менять масштаб (данные-->пиксели)  и засечки с цифрами и менять количество засечек. В общем замечательные, гибкие оси (кроме моей задачи) кодом в несколько строк.

Comment: @andrey.ilinskiy Я уважаю ваш выбор. Но d3 сложна в освоении. Может быть попробуете Snapjs библиотеку она попроще.

Comment: попробую, спасибо. Хотя сейчас пользуюсь SVG.js если говорить о библиотеках для работы с svg. Кстати у них на сайте есть сравнение со snap. Довольно интересно.