# Меню с горизонтальной вкладкой с вкладками прокрутки, как у BBC

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

У меня есть простое горизонтальное меню, более похожее на вкладки. Я хочу, чтобы оно работало, как меню со вкладками  у приложения `BBC`, так что, когда в меню больше элементов, это позволит горизонтальную прокрутку в обоих направлениях.

То же самое в моем коде [здесь:](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZRaee)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал сделать это несколько раз, но ничего не работает. Завернул меню в `div` с фиксированной шириной и попытался сделать `scroll-able`, но это не сработало, поскольку он всегда добавляет `scroll-bar`.

Я пытался сделать его как карусель, но это тоже не помогло мне.

Есть ли аналогичный плагин для HTML-сайта. Панель навигации, используемая приложением BBC. Я  хотел бы иметь, что-то похожее для веб-страницы на основе `HTML` для мобильной версии.

```
<div class="tab-nav-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">MenuONE</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a href="#">MTWO</a></li>
    <li class="three"><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
    <li class="four"><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
    <li class="five"><a href="#">MenuFIVE</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content-wrapper">
  <div class="tab1-c">
    <p>This is ONE.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab2-c">
    <p>This is TWO</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab3-c">
    <p>This is THREE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab4-c">
    <p>This is FOUR</p>
  </div>

  <div>
```

Перевод вопроса: [Horizontal Tab based menu with scrolling tabs@Learning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35742071/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742071/horizontal-tab-based-menu-with-scrolling-tabs/35831385#35831385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю поможет кому или нет и то ли это что требуется, но когда на мобильных устройствах требуется горизонтальный скролл делаю так (на десктопе ничего не будет, ибо все помещается, можно просто айфрейм растянуть, протестить), скроллбар есть всегда, но он скрыт за оверфлоу родителя. Для мобильного же, не знаю будет работать на эмитации браузерной (тач событие + сайт), но можно попробовать выделить все элементы (он начнет выделять текст пунктов и прокрутит полоску)

```js
// Примерная логика, придется ещё позиционировать табы относительно
// кнопки js'ом (если надо что бы меню открывалось под кнопкой)

$(function(){
  menuInit();
});

function menuInit()
{
  var listItem = $('.menu_list-item'),
      tabItem = $('.menu_tab-item');
      
  listItem.on('click', onClick);

  function onClick()
  {
    tabItem.removeClass('show');
    tabItem.eq($(this).index()).addClass('show');
  }
}
```

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.menu_wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu_list {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 -30px;
  padding: 0 0 30px;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #888;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.menu_list-item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_tab {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.menu_tab-item { display: none; }

.menu_tab-item.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu_wrapper">
    <ul class="menu_list">
      <li class="menu_list-item">Tab 1</li>
      <li class="menu_list-item">Tab 2</li>
      <li class="menu_list-item">Tab 3</li>
      <li class="menu_list-item">Tab 4</li>
      <li class="menu_list-item">Tab 5</li>
      <li class="menu_list-item">Tab 6</li>
      <li class="menu_list-item">Tab 7</li>
      <li class="menu_list-item">Tab 8</li>
      <li class="menu_list-item">Tab 9</li>
      <li class="menu_list-item">Tab 10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_tab">
    <div class="menu_tab-item"> 
      Tab Contant 1
    </div>
    <div class="menu_tab-item"> 
      Tab Contant 2
    </div>
    <div class="menu_tab-item"> 
      Tab Contant 3
    </div>
    <div class="menu_tab-item"> 
      Tab Contant 4
    </div>
    <div class="menu_tab-item"> 
      Tab Contant 5
    </div>
    <div class="menu_tab-item"> 
      Tab Contant 6
    </div>
    <div class="menu_tab-item"> 
      Tab Contant 7
    </div>
    <div class="menu_tab-item"> 
      Tab Contant 8
    </div>
    <div class="menu_tab-item"> 
      Tab Contant 9
    </div>
    <div class="menu_tab-item"> 
      Tab Contant 10
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Норм, с имитацией мобильного устройства можно потестить

Comment: немного не то. Но плюс за инициативу (+) и рабочий пример. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете сделать это с помощью  `Owl Carousel 2` Как видите, вы можете горизонтально прокручивать вкладки с помощью мыши и горизонтальной полосы прокрутки.

Кроме того, я использовал `responsive` вариант, чтобы настроить количество показов вкладок на разной ширине, но вы можете изменить это.

```js
//OWL Carousel
$('.tabs').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: false,
    dots: false,
    responsive: {
      0:   {items: 2},
      250: {items: 3},
      400: {items: 4},
      500: {items: 5}
    }
});

//Tabs
$('.tabs li a').click(function() {
  var activeLink = $(this).data('target');
  var targetTab = $('.tab.'+activeLink);
  
  targetTab.siblings().removeClass('active');
  targetTab.addClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 2px auto;
  background: #353434;
  padding: 0;
}

.tab-content {
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.owl-controls {
  display: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}

li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-content > div {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > div.active {
  display: block;
}

.info {
  text-align: center;
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css  rel="stylesheet"/>  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<p class="info">Grab and drag tabs for scroll</p>

<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="item"><a data-target="tab-one">Tab One</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a data-target="tab-two">Tab Two</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a data-target="tab-three">Tab Three</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a data-target="tab-four">Tab Four</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a data-target="tab-five">Tab Five</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a data-target="tab-six">Tab Six</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a data-target="tab-seven">Tab Seven</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a data-target="tab-eight">Tab Eight</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab tab-one active">One <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, iusto!</div>
  <div class="tab tab-two">Two <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
  <div class="tab tab-three">Three</div>
  <div class="tab tab-four">Four</div>
  <div class="tab tab-five">Five</div>
  <div class="tab tab-six">Six</div>
  <div class="tab tab-seven">Seven</div>
  <div class="tab tab-eight">Eight</div>
</div>
```

**Наведите курсор на пункт меню и прокручивайте его по горизонтали до нужного пункта.**

Перевод ответа: [Horizontal Tab based menu with scrolling tabs @Nenad Vracar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35831385/7394871)

Comment: Прошу меня извинить, но ваши примеры на фидле не работают так, как вы описали.

Comment: Код на нашем сниппете не рабочий - разбираюсь, сейчас. На enSO сообщений об ошибке нет, код взят **1:1** оттуда. Пока нашел, что плагин `owlCarousel` по старому адресу недоступен. Этот плагин есть на гитхабе - https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2, но пока не удается избавиться от ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и старания )

Comment: @alexoander теперь работает